# Systematically create multiple instances of custom hook to extend store entities with additional methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Let's say I have a hook that returns an entity's state, as well as extends it with some methods for enacting mutations:

```js
// Loads an entity from the store and provides methods to update and remove it
const useEntity = (entityId) => {
  // Selects the entity from the store
  const entity = useSelector(selectEntity(entityId));

  // Updates the entity in the store
  const update = (value) => {
    // ...logic
  };

  // Removes the entity from the store
  const remove = () => {
    // ...logic
  };
  
  return {
    entity, // The entity from the store
    update, // The update method
    remove  // The remove method
  };
};
```

I would like to create a "wrapper" hook that "extends" all entities in the store using my `useEntity` hook

```js
// Extends EVERY entity in the store with the useEntity hook defined previously
const useEntities = () => {
  // Selects all entities from the store
  const allEntities = useSelector(selectAllEntities);
  const extendedEntities = allEntities.map((entity) => useEntity(entity.id));
  return extendedEntities;
}
```

Obviously, the logic in `useEntities` violates the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) as the hooks get called inside a loop.

What then is the correct way to extend my entities to have the additional custom methods?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like

```js
const extendedEntities = useEntities()
  extendedEntities[0].update("New value") // Updates the value for entity 0
  extendedEntieis[6].remove() // Removes entity 6
  extendedEntities[3].entity // returns the value of entity 3
  // ...etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying so heavily on the `useSelector` hook you could modify the `useEntity` hook to be a `augmentEntity` utility that is either passed or closes over a reference to the `store` object where it can internally select the state it requires.

In other words, recall that `selectEntity(entityId)` is a selector function that is passed the current Redux state and returns a computed value. Convert `useSelector(selectEntity(entityId))` to `selectEntity(entityId)(state)`.

Something like the following:

```js
/** Loads an entity from the store and provides methods to update and remove it */
const augmentEntity = (entityId) => {
  const state = store.getState();

  // Selects the entity from the store
  const entity = selectEntity(entityId)(state);

  // Updates the entity in the store
  const update = (value) => {
    // ...logic
  };

  // Removes the entity from the store
  const remove = () => {
    // ...logic
  };
  
  return {
    entity, // The entity from the store
    update, // The update method
    remove  // The remove method
  };
};
```

```js
const useEntities = () => {
  // Selects all entities from the store
  const allEntities = useSelector(selectAllEntities);

  // Augments all entities with update/remove functions
  return allEntities.map((entity) => augmentEntity(entity.id));
};
```

Since `selectAllEntities` already returns all the entities there is probably no reason to again select specific entities directly, just pass the mapped entities instead of their ids to the utility and augment as needed.

Example:

```js
const augmentEntity = (entity) => {
  // Updates the entity in the store
  const update = (value) => {
    // ...logic
  };

  // Removes the entity from the store
  const remove = () => {
    // ...logic
  };
  
  return {
    entity, // The entity from the store
    update, // The update method
    remove  // The remove method
  };
};
```

```js
const useEntities = () => {
  // Selects all entities from the store
  const allEntities = useSelector(selectAllEntities);

  // Augments all entities with update/remove functions
  return allEntities.map(augmentEntity);
};
```

Comment: This is nothing short of ingenious. My simplified version does not capture the fact that I am actually reliant on React hooks in to extendEntity function, and as such, ultimately, I cannot use this proposal as it, but I am very impressed with the out of the box solution

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich Thanks, kind words, but you give me too much credit though.  Bummer it can't be extended to your actual use case though.